# Add user to classify files into specific file type column (Metadata)

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, metadata-navigation

In my SharePoint library a lot of users can upload files, unfortunately when the files get custom  metadata and then I always have to go manually and categorize them.

Having it in mind that the users are not experienced. Is there an easy way when they upload the files a pop up or something to shop up and make them categorize the files.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I used to meet this before. As a workaround, you could require one column contains information to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: I got a small questions. If is possible to go to an existing  created column and  switch the Require that this column contains information from No to Yes.

Comment: Yes,you can.Just go to  list settings and click the column to switch the Require that this column contains information from No to Yes.